# Is there a verb that means "tracks and changes"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a verb that means "tracks and changes"? I don't think there is so can you find a way to formulate the following sentence in a way that doesn't sound too weird and incomprehensible?

For example:

> The robot tracks the national average height of the U.S. and changes
>   its own height to match the national average.

Comment: How could it be possible for a single verb (that means both things) to apply to a *single* action? The example sentence is ***not*** an example of such a thing. The robot doesn't *track and change* X. Instead, it tracks one thing and changes something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated sentence in the question seems perfectly grammatical and comprehensible. I don't know of any robot which can currently do that, but I have no trouble imagining one.

Answer (score 1):

There are verbs that suggest both these actions such as *calibrate*, *conform*, *harmonize*, and so on, but you'll still have to explain what the robot is actually doing:

> The robot **attunes itself** to the average height in the U.S. by **adjusting** its own height to match.